# How to set boolean to null instead of false, if not specified in REST query

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

I have a Spring Boot REST API and one of the endpoints takes requests that include a body, like this:

```
@GetMapping("/search")
public List<ItemDto> searchDevice(@RequestBody ItemDto itemDto){
    // code
}
```

The DTO looks like this:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class ItemDto {

//other fields

@JsonProperty(value = "status")
private boolean status;

// getters and setters
}
```

So my problem is this: when I send a request not containing `status` it defaults to `false`, which is not the behaviour I need. I want status to be `null`, when it is not specified. How can I achieve this?

Another interesting behaviour is that `status` is `false` even when I specify it in the query as `"status": null`

As you can see, I already tried to use the annotations `@JsonInclude` and `@JsonProperty`, that I've seen recommended in similiar questions, but they are not working for me. The boolean still defaults to `false`. Is there any other fix for this?

Comment: boolean is a primitive type. primitives can not be null. You can use the wrapper type Boolean, though.

Comment: Oh wow, thank you this helped! I can't believe I missed that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`boolean` is a primitive type which means it is not a Java object. As such it cannot be `null`, just true or false. You can just replace it by the Java object equivalent which is `Boolean` and then it will be able to be `null`. In Java there is boxing an unboxing which allow seamless conversion between primitive type and Java object equivalent (or wrapper) when needed, so you can still do `if(yourBoolean)` if it's a `Boolean` but be aware that this can throw NPE if `yourBoolean` is `null`.

Note that it is not usually good practice to do that, you shouldn't have a different logic when the boolean isn't here as when it's `null`, as it is not really a boolean anymore. If you have control over the input and you really have 3 states, then look into using an enum as it might be a better choice (or you can use 2 boolean).

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the Boolean wrapper for the status variable

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class ItemDto {

@JsonProperty(value = "status")
private Boolean status;

// getters and setters
}
```